# Configuring the WSO2 IS to external LDAP

Tags: ldap, wso2, openldap, wso2-identity-server

I've been following this [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS410/Connect+the+WSO2+API+Manager+to+an+External+LDAP+User+Store) on how to connect to external LDAP server from WSO2 Identity Server.

Now I am stuck at running the product. Upon running the WSO2 IS, I got an error saying that the admin user is not exist in PRIMARY. If I am using the existing configuration, everything went well. So i thought, this might be because of the configuration that I make at the `user-mgt.xml` and `tenant-mgt.xml`

This is my external LDAP configuration:
[LDAP User and Group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xEn6.png)

This is my `user-mgt.xml` file looks like

```
<UserManager>
<Realm>
<Configuration>
    <AddAdmin>true</AddAdmin>
        <AdminRole>admin</AdminRole>
        <AdminUser>
            <UserName>admin</UserName>
            <Password>*****</Password>
        </AdminUser>
        <EveryOneRoleName>everyone</EveryOneRoleName> <!-- By default users in this role sees the registry root -->
        <Property name="isCascadeDeleteEnabled">true</Property>
        <Property name="initializeNewClaimManager">true</Property>
        <Property name="dataSource">jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</Property>
    </Configuration>
<UserStoreManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager">
    <Property name="TenantManager">org.wso2.carbon.user.core.tenant.CommonHybridLDAPTenantManager</Property>
    <Property name="ConnectionURL">ldap://10.251.45.200:389</Property>
    <Property name="ConnectionName">cn=ldap,dc=ei,dc=local</Property>
    <Property name="ConnectionPassword">P@ssw0rd</Property>
    <Property name="AnonymousBind">false</Property>
    <Property name="UserSearchBase">ou=People,dc=ei,dc=local</Property>
    <Property name="UserEntryObjectClass">identityPerson</Property>
    <Property name="UserNameAttribute">uid</Property>
    <Property name="UserNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=person)(uid=?))</Property>
    <Property name="UserNameListFilter">(objectClass=person)</Property>
    <Property name="DisplayNameAttribute"/>
    <Property name="ReadGroups">true</Property>
    <Property name="WriteGroups">true</Property>
    <Property name="GroupSearchBase">ou=Group,dc=ei,dc=local</Property>
    <Property name="GroupEntryObjectClass">groupOfNames</Property>
    <Property name="GroupNameAttribute">cn</Property>
    <Property name="GroupNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=groupOfNames)(cn=?))</Property>
    <Property name="GroupNameListFilter">(objectClass=groupOfNames)</Property>
    <Property name="MembershipAttribute">member</Property>
    <Property name="SCIMEnabled">true</Property>
    <Property name="IsBulkImportSupported">false</Property>
    <Property name="EmptyRolesAllowed">false</Property>
</UserStoreManager>
</Realm>
```

Please help me here, I so stuck at this process. Any advice would be great !

Comment: I have noticed you have another user in the LDAP. Could you able to log in using the 'tester' ?

Comment: @senthalan, do you mean login in the Identity Server management console login page ?

Comment: yes. Identity server management console or dashboard (/dashboard)

Comment: @senthalan, what would the password be ? i never stated the password when i create the user

Comment: Do you have a user called "admin" in the external LDAP ? Under "ou=People,dc=ei,dc=local"

Comment: @JayangaKaushalya did you see the above diagram ? how is it different from the uid=admin with the briefcase icon and the other user uid=tester with the person icon ?

Comment: Can you check the object class of the "admin" user and validate it is a "idenitytPerson" or a "person".

Comment: @JayangaKaushalya I am so sorry. I dont understand what I am suppose to do. Maybe there is a guide on how to create an admin user to the ldap. I would be so glad

Comment: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Fuse_MQ_Enterprise/7.1/html/Security_Guide/files/LDAP-AddUserEntries.html 
Make sure the object class is a "person" or "identityPerson"

Comment: The image you have attached is from apache directory studio, right? If so check the connection details added there and use the same for ConnectionName and ConnectionPassword. And you need to have the correct UserEntryObjectClass as well in the config.

Comment: @MadurangaSiriwardena Hi there. yup, its form apache directory studio. I manage to figure out already. apparently, my configuration at the WSO2 IS is incorrect.

Comment: Please add the fix you did as an answer.